# ConnectionException connecting a Eve REST API to a MongoDB instance

Tags: python, api, mongodb, rest, eve

I just installed the 'eve demo' I can't get it to start working.

The error is:

> eve.io.base.ConnectionException: Error initializing the driver. Make sure the database serveris running. Driver exception: OperationFailure(u"command SON([('authenticate', 1), ('user', u'user'), ('nonce', u'cec66353cb35b6f5'), ('key', u'14817e596653376514b76248055e1d4f')]) failed: auth fails",)

I have mongoDB running, and I have installed [Eve](http://python-eve.org) and Python2.7.

I create the  [run.py](http://pastebin.com/HVJykT43) and the [settings.py](http://pastebin.com/jNukQAvW) required.

What is not working ? am I missing something ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the MongoDB user/pw combo you configured in your `settings.py` has not been set at the db level. From the mongo shell type `use <dbname>`, then `db.system.users.find()` to get a list of authorized users for `<dbname>`. It is probably empty; add the user as needed (see the [MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.addUser/)).

Answer (score 4):

1. get your mongodb's dbname,username and password from setting.py,eg:

   ```
   MONGO_USERNAME = 'username'

   MONGO_PASSWORD = 'password'

   MONGO_DBNAME = 'apitest'
   ```
2. login in mongod server with mongo,and make sure your username in dbname's system.user collection.you can query authenticated users in that database with the following operation:

   ```
   use apitest

   db.system.users.find()
   ```
3. if username doesn't exist in system.users,then you can use db.addUser command to add a user to system.users collection.eg:

   ```
   use apitest

   db.addUser{'username','password'}
   ```

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales Yes,this problem is happened to me, and I use above  steps address it. also thanks for Nicola Iarocci。

Comment: Great answer. Just one issue. It should be: db.addUser('username', 'password') ... Using the {...} won't work.